# Number of partitions of a $\mathbb{N}^n$ vector

Tags: integer-partitions

Using power series, we can find an formula for the partitions of an integer.

Can we do the same for the partitions of a vector? (I tried to apply the same technique, but failed due to the fact that the integer partitions of each component depends on the component.)